# What is the difference between Nav.Link vs Link vs NavLink in react router DOM and react bootstrap?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, react-bootstrap

I am confused about these three Links, what are the different ways to use them?

- Nav.Link
- Link
- NavLink i

Do they have different use cases?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- [`Nav.Link`](https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/blob/master/src/NavLink.tsx): The `Nav.Link` component is maintained by `react-bootstrap` and returns an anchor (`<a />`) tag by default.
- [`Link`](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#link): Is a specialized anchor (`<a />`) tag that link specifically to internal routes maintained by a `react-router`/`react-router-dom` router component. It does not handle external links.
- [`NavLink`](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#navlink): A `<NavLink>` is a special kind of `<Link>` that knows whether or not it is "active".

Use the `Link` or `NavLink` components when you need to link to internal pages in your app. Use the `Nav.Link` component from `react-bootstrap` component ***if*** you are already using `react-bootstrap` and need to link to external or internal pages.

If you need to use `Nav.Link` and link to internal pages then pass `Link` or `NavLink` as the `component` of the `Nav.Link` component and pass the appropriate required props through.

External Example:

```
<Nav.Link href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72091197/what-is-the-difference-between-nav-link-vs-link-vs-navlink-in-react-router-dom-a" >
  Some internal link
</Nav.Link>
```

Internal Example:

```
<Nav.Link
  as={Link}
  to="/internalPage"
>
  Some internal link
</Nav.Link>
```

Note: If using `Link` or `NavLink` they have an invariant check that requires them to be used within a `react-router-dom` routing context provided by a router.